# Reading a textfile using InputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream

How can I read a text file like in android app:

```
"1.something written
2.in this file
3.is to be read by
4.the InputStream
..."
```

so I can be returned a string like:

```
"something written\nin this file\nis to be read by\nthe InputStream"
```

what I thought of is(Pseudocode):

```
make an inputstream
is = getAssest().open("textfile.txt");  //in try and catch
for loop{
string = is.read() and if it equals "." (i.e. from 1., 2., 3. etc) add "/n" ...
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.*;

public class FileDemo1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            playWithRawFiles();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problems: " + e.getMessage(), 1).show();
        }
    }

    public void playWithRawFiles() throws IOException {      
        String str = "";
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();            
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.my_base_data);
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            if (is != null) {                            
                while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
                    buf.append(str + "\n" );
                }                
            }
        } finally {
            try { is.close(); } catch (Throwable ignore) {}
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), buf.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `BufferedReader` to read the input stream. As `BufferedReader` will read text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines. `InputStream` represents an input stream of bytes. `reader.readLine()` will read the file line by line.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    out.append(line);   // add everything to StringBuilder 
    // here you can have your logic of comparison.
    if(line.toString().equals(".")) {
        // do something
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
File fe = new File("abc.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fe);
byte data[] = new byte[fis.available()];
fis.read(data);
fis.close();
String str = new String(data);
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: It would help to provide context to how and where to use your code

Comment: if you have any txt file and u want to read that text file using  FileInputStream you can do so and.......... in your  File fe=new File(abc.txt); and this will be display in your console  read data String str=new String(data);
                System.out.println(str);