# How to parse result returned by `ls -l ` using shell command - Android

Tags: android, shell-exec

Pls I really need help on how to parse result returned by the 
" ls -l "  Command
I really need this to get list and details of private directories ( such as "/data/data" dir) in my file manager app after the user has been granted su access

Below is an example of result expected to be returned after executing the command 
getRunTime().exec("ls -l /data/data");

```
> u0_a192@Infinix_X507:/ $ ls -l /storage/sdcard0
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-14 22:23 2go
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-15 11:26 360
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          2015-08-13 10:25 Android
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-29 21:09 AppProjects
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-01-01 00:00 Assistant
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-18 10:44 Camera360
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-11 21:29 DCIM
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r      808 2015-08-19 05:36 Document.txt
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-30 07:19 Download
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-17 19:25 FM Recording
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-24 17:18 Flash Share
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-24 10:03 KingMaster
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-14 04:39 Kingroot
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-21 06:49 ManifestViewer
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-30 19:25 Movies
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-30 19:25 Music
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-13 06:55 OGWhatsApp
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-23 14:00 OGWhatsApp Old
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-11 17:00 Pictures
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-23 10:59 Rec
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-01-01 00:00 Ringtones
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-24 17:18 ShareSDK
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-21 14:41 Simple Android Server
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-23 11:19 VidMate
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-14 04:00 WhatsApp
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-30 14:55 Wps
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-30 17:19 bluetooth
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-24 15:11 com.facebook.orca
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r  2999645 2015-08-30 14:55 demo.mp4
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-29 17:11 dianxin
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-29 21:29 documents
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r      112 2015-08-15 07:41 e_config
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-18 07:00 iQuran
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-23 14:00 icloudzone
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-14 11:53 jamb_cbt_science
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r      112 2015-08-13 20:24 kr-stock-conf
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-11 17:45 media
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-23 14:00 mtklog
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-01-01 01:00 obb
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r  1132508 2015-08-14 11:54 pq_commercial.pdf
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r        6 2015-08-23 13:44 qs.pid
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-16 07:33 romtoolbox
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-24 10:03 tbslog
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-17 04:25 tencent
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r 69565980 2015-08-23 17:01 update.zip
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2015-08-14 22:26 viber
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r  8514230 2015-08-30 10:43 vlc.apk
u0_a192@Infinix_X507:/ $
```

I have already seen a similar solution, but was in php using the ftp_rawlist() function, but I want a Java / Android solution please....

I know this would require RegEx or Pattern...etc..
Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Every file listing should be on a new line. Split the output by newlines and parse from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you [read the output line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825374/reading-a-textfile-using-inputstream).

Then you [split each line by whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters):

```
if (str[0] == 'd') // Directory
    String[] parsed = str.split("\\s+", 6);
else
    String[] parsed = str.split("\\s+", 7);
```

Then you have a nice string array, where `parsed[6]` is the file name, or `parsed[5]` if it's a directory, because `ls -l` won't print size for directories. It won't mess filenames with spaces inside, as an additional bonus.

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer really worked, but doesn't for files that neither starts with 'd' or '-', I encountered some problem with those that starts with 'l'

Answer (score 0):

You're making this harder than it needs to be; Android has a `File` class with this very functionality built in:

```
File f = new File(path);        
File files[] = f.listFiles();
```

That will give you an array of files and folders in that path.  Documentation on `File` can be found here:
http://www.developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Comment: Thanks, I use that for normal file  list but the File class cannot list private directories, especially with su command

Comment: If the application is running as root (which it would have to be to perform `ls` as root anyway), it shouldn't need the `su` command.  What private directories specifically are you speaking about?

Comment: App itslef cannot be run under root account, even when granted superuser permissions - it executs scripts under root account using 'su' shell command.

Comment: @Sector95, the device does not need to be root to run `ls`. Also, the developer indeed needs to call `su` and keep the shell open to run binaries as root.

Answer (score 0):

What data are you trying to parse for? If you're looking for a specific string, you could use grep. (At least, on Linux you can use grep, I'm assuming it's included in Android as well, but I haven't tried it out myself.)

`ls -l | grep targetString`

Comment: Just adding as I do the same thing with Windows using 'cygwin', a wonderful tool for simulating the linux commands on Windows.