# Read line from an InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm using an `InputStream` to read some data and I want to read characters until new line or '\n'.

The `InputStream` is a generic input stream of bytes not tight to any specific implementation or any source (like a file).

Comment: Use a `BufferedReader` and its `readLine` method. Dupe of: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java

Comment: I disagree that it is a duplicate question. The questions [1] and [2] are about reading from a  file, answers are using API specific to file. Question [3] has been asked *after* that one (10 months after) and has far less votes and tractions, it would have been question [3] to be marked as a duplicated. [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-can-i-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java [2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825374/reading-a-textfile-using-inputstream [3] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250814/read-a-line-of-a-file-using-an-inputstream

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You should use `BufferedReader` with `FileReader` if your read from a file

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile));
```

or with `InputStreamReader` if you read from any other `InputStream`

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Then use its readLine() method in a loop

```
while(reader.ready()) {
     String line = reader.readLine();
}
```

But if you really love InputStream then you can use a loop like this

```
InputStream stream; 
char c; 
String s = ""; 
do {
   c = stream.read(); 
   if (c == '\n')
      break; 
   s += c + "";
} while (c != -1);
```

Comment: I was hoping for something bulid-in :/.
Btw. BufferedReader doesn't support encoding.

Comment: What do you mean by built in? BufferedReader is in the java standard library and it actually does, you can specify the encoding in this way:

``new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("path/to/file"), "UTF8"));``

Comment: Didn't know that. I found that you can do this with InputStream and then I wanted to find out if there is any way how to make InputStream readLines without a while cycle. I will try mentioned BufferedReader constructor...

Comment: well for anyone who stumbles on this in the future like me, it's FileReader not FileInputStreamReader

Comment: reader.ready() does not always return true, leading to no lines read. More failure proven:
String line = null; while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { ... }

Comment: (1) `FileInputStreamReader` does not exist.  (2) `while (reader.ready())` is invalid. `ready()` is not a test for end of stream, as it states clearly in the Javadoc. The correct test is `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)`. This code is quite capable of stopping before end of stream. Answer is untested nonsense.

Answer (score 11):

### TL;DR

### **Use `BufferedReader` within the `try-with` block, which will close the resource after finishing with it.**

---

It is possible to read the input stream with BufferedReader and with Scanner. If you don't have a good reason, it is better to use BufferedRead (for broad discussion BufferedReader vs Scanner [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)).

I would also suggest using the Buffered Reader with try-with-resources to make sure the resource are auto-closed. [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

See the following code

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `while (reader.ready())` is invalid. `ready()` is not a test for end of stream. The correct test is `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)`. This code is quite capable of stopping before end of stream.

Comment: @user207421, updated. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6):

For files, the following will let you read each line:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public static void readText throws FileNotFoundException(){

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));

     while(scan.hasNextLine()){
         String line = scan.nextLine();

     }
}
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with InputStreams

Comment: Yes it does if slightly rewritten - `var scan = new Scanner(InputStream source)`

Comment: The code with `val scan = Scanner(inputstream)` solved my problem reading chunked HTTP responses.

Comment: @rwst I don't see how. There's nothing in `Scanner` that knows anything about HTTP chunking. I imagine that dropping `reader.ready()` was the real solution.