# HTTPUrlConnection not working

Tags: android-studio

I have a project on Android Studio using url to extract content. I using HttpURLConnection, create a openConnection but it not working.
My code below:

```
try
{
    URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825374/reading-a-textfile-using-inputstream/");
    HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpcon.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
    String content = httpcon.getContentType();
    tv.setText(content);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    tv.setText("Can't connect");
}
```

But when i use the same type of connection in eclipse, it's work. Is that difference between Android Studio and Eclipse?
Thank you for reading.